# reduce space between datatables at RMarkdown

Tags: datatable, rstudio, markdown, r-markdown, knitr

I just wanted to know if there´s any way to reduce the space between to tables (one on top of the following) in an Rmarkdown sheet. I´ve tried doing

````
<div style="width: 100%;margin-top: 1px;margin-bottom: 1px;">
<div style="width: 63%;float: bottom;margin-top: 1px;margin-bottom: 1px;">

```{r, echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE,message=FALSE, results='asis'}
#here the two tables I need to print at the Markdown
````

```
But it doesn´t work. Do you have any sugestions? Thanks a lot!
```

Answer (score 0):

The minimal distance between two tables is one line - otherwise they would be merged (as you can see in my example):
[Example with 1 line distance and without one line distance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3AWK8.png)

What is the output format of your md document?

Comment: Hello! I´m not able to merge the tables as both are customized in different ways by column. Anyway, I could solve it by adding negative values to the margin-top. it result like this:

Comment: <div style="width: 100%;margin-top: 50px;margin-bottom: 0px;">

```{r, echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE,message=FALSE, results='asis'}
#one datatable here
```
</div>

<div style="width: 66%;float: bottom;margin-top:-19px;margin-bottom: 50px;">
```{r, echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE,message=FALSE, results='asis'}
#the otherone here (negative margin-top)
```
</div>

Answer (score 0):

I could finnaly solve it by using a negative margin-top for the second table.

```
<div style="width: 100%;margin-top: 50px;margin-bottom: 0px;"> 
{r, echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE,message=FALSE, results='asis'} 
#one datatable here 
</div> 

<div style="width: 66%;float: bottom;margin-top:-19px;margin-bottom: 50px;"> 

{r, echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE,message=FALSE, results='asis'} 
#the otherone here (negative margin-top) 

</div>
```